# Is there an online Operating System that works like a real OS?

Tags: operating-system

Is there an online Operating system that runs like a real OS? These are the features that I expect.

- Online.
- Should save changes such as saving files, etc.
- Free.
- Should be able to log in with username and password.
- No ads.

Should be able to run stuff like `git clone` and manage files

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

*PS: Linux is preferred(especially Kali Linux)*

Comment: It would help to know how this would be useful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: edited. should be much clearer

Answer (score 1):

It's a tall order asking for free and no ads.

However, [JSLinux](https://bellard.org/jslinux/) looks like it might fit the bill for you.  I haven't used it but it sounds like it will work.

> **JSLinux** 
> is fully functional Linux running entirely in a web browser, meaning if you have almost any modern web browser suddenly you can run a basic version of Linux on any computer.
>
> This emulator is written in JavaScript and supported on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Internet Explorer. You can refer to the official technical notes about this fantastic emulator.

Quoted from [geekflare](https://geekflare.com/run-linux-from-a-web-browser/)

---

This is a screenshot from the website which is strictly functional.

[image: screenshot]